# How to concurrently run blocking and non blocking code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn, concurrent-processing

I need to be able to run some code that is going to be blocking and some other code that will then, when blocked, start some other actions.

The use-case is the follows:

I have a file, called *`index.ts`*, running an express and socket server

I have a testfile, called *`test.spec.ts`*, that needs to be able to start the express server and then initiate some commands for running tests either via HTTP request or socket message(I would prefer HTTP)

The only way I found to keep the webserver alive is instantiating it with

```
import { spawnSync } from 'child_process';

spawnSync('ts-node', ['path/to/index.ts"], { cwd: "path/to/workdir"});
```

which will block until the child process is killed ( could be up to 30min later ).

Is there a way to split into two processes, one that gets blocked when starting it and one continuing to work that exposes some functions for interactions with the test file?

My target would look like this:

```
// index.ts

import * as express from "express";
const app = express();

const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

```
// test.spec.ts

import { spawnSync } from 'child_process';

describe("Test",()=>{

  it("Test", async ()=>{

    // create somehow a child process that should block
    const childProcess = ...
    childProcess.do(spawnSync('ts-node', ['path/to/index.ts'], {cwd: 'path/to/workdir'}) //should block now

    // the following code should run in parallel
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 5000)); //wait some time until the webserver is ready

    fetch('http://localhost:3000').then((ret)=>{
      expect(ret,'to be Hello World').to.contain('Hello World!");
    })
    ... // more tests
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason and a possible solution myself.

Node always runs in a single process therefore it can't work. Luckily I was able to discover a totally different approach. I installed the `npm-run-all` package and created a new script in my `package.json` file calling `run-p script1 script2`. This way I can run both in parallel and the process with the webserver stays alive until all tests are run